# Yii. Распаковка архива.

Tags: yii

Здравсвуйте. Не судите строго. 
Зачем в начале при распаковывании архива с фрейм ворком нужно делать это через командную строку и в ней вводить:

```
cd c:\
cd WebServers\home\y1\www\framework
php -f yiic webapp C:\WebServers53\home\y1\www
```

Ведь можно, к примеру, скопировать и распаковать архив с этими же файлами, для чего такой "геморрой"?
Из-за этого все файлы с кодировкой Ansi, а не UTF-8

Comment: > Из-за этого все файлы с кодировкой Ansi, а не UTF-8

оооох

Файл, содержащий исключительно латинские символы, в UTF-8 не будет отличаться от большинства кодировок, потому что будет содержать только ASCII-символы.

Создание приложение наверняка затрагивает нечто большее, чем просто распаковку файлов. И, кстати, вышеописанное влегкую выполняется в одну строчку.

Comment: Я понимаю, но из-за этой особенности приходится каждый, в котором есть кириллица пересохранять в UTF-8